# display a symfony post-validation error in an embeded Form

Tags: forms, symfony1, validation, customvalidator

I have a form witch contains embededForms.

the Post-Validator:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorCallback(
    array('callback' => array($this, 'myPostValidator'))
  )
);
```

I throw an error in the myPostValidator method:

```
$error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid ' . $values['embededform1']['field']);
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('field' => $error));
```

now I get an global error for the root-form.

I want to display the error next to the correct field.

```
$values['embededform1']['field']
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/c116a783b1d8fe82?pli=1

Comment: Uwe: that link is about Symfony2, which is an entirely different subject.

Comment: Where is the postvalidator set? In the embedded form or in the container form?

Comment: in the containerform. I need a value from the containerform to validate the embedded form.

Comment: Hi all pls help me with this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498386/symfony-1-4-forms-display-a-post-validation-error-in-an-embeded-form-with-one-t

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to add the post validator in the embedded form. While embedding it will copy the validator to the container form, and your code for throwing the exception should work as expected.

Alternative you can try the following in the callback on your container form:

```
$error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid');
$errorschema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('field' => $error));
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('embeddedformname' => $errorschema));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, post validators in embedded form's aren't run when the container form is validated.

Comment: That's not true, they are copied while embedding to the container form, as is the entire validatorschema.

Answer (score 0):

```
$error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid');
$errorschema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('field' => $error));
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('embeddedformname' => $errorschema));
```

this worked for me.